# Kerberos issue through RRAS VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, authentication, kerberos

I set up a Windows VPN infrastructure with RRAS NPS CA roles. A user certificate is deployed on each laptop and are joined to a single domain. VPN use IKEv2.
VPN is UP, communications are working to our internals networks, except applications that use integrated authentication.

The issue seems related to Kerberos authentication because I have the following error on the event viewer

Source : LSA
Event : 40960
The failure code from authentication protocol Kerberos was "that request is not supported"(0xc00000bb)

When i'm directly connected to my internal network, everything is working well.

The VPN infrastructure seemms to be causing the issue.

Thanks for your help :)

Edit :
We use Remote Desktop Manager which try to authenticate to a SQL Server. This error is returned.
[SQL Server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwjyl.png)

Comment: `applications that use integrated authentication.` What applications?

Comment: Remote Desktop Manager